# How to toggle javascript functions using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two javascript functions

```
 function A(){ 
   alert("A() function is called");
 }

function B(){
    alert("B() function is called");
 }

 $("#button").click(function(){
 // I need to toggle A() and B() here
 });
```

How can I achieve this, can any one please help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do by applying class to the button and write depends on class

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6fLkrmzb/)

```
 <input type="button" class="callA" value="click me" id="button" />

 $("#button").click(function(){

   if($(this).hasClass('callA')){
           A();
    }
   else
    {
          B();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you could store a flag which stores the state of the element, and therefore which function to call. Here's an example which uses a class:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var $el = $(this).toggleClass('foo');
    $el.hasClass('foo') ? A() : B();
});
```

You could bind/unbind event handlers on each successive click, but this quickly becomes unwieldy and a pain to maintain.

For the sake of completeness, here's an example that uses a `data` attribute instead:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var $el = $(this).data('foo', !$(this).data('foo'));
    $el.data('foo') ? A() : B();
});
```

Comment: would it make more sense to use a data attribute like `data-function="A"` and then use that as your flag? I wouldn't want to have the class conflict somewhere, and data-attributes exist for reasons like this.

Comment: `class`, `data` attribute, local variable, `localStorage`.. take your pick. As I stated, I simply used a class as an example.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the binding

```
function A(){ 
   alert("A() function is called");
   $("#button").off("click", A).on("click", B);
 }

function B(){
   alert("A() function is called");
   $("#button").off("click", B).on("click", A);
 }

 $("#button").on("click", A);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean variable (true) and set it to false after calling the first fonction. Then if false call the second one and set the boolean variable again (to true).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.data()` to set a variable on the element itself, which tells you which function to call.

```js
function A() {
  alert("A() function is called");
}

function B() {
  alert("B() function is called");
}

$("#button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).data('AorB') == 'B') {
    B();
    $(this).data('AorB', 'A');
  } else {
    A();
    $(this).data('AorB', 'B');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click me</button>
```